# Acredito ser um erro de overflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Criei dois arrays do seguinte modo

```
array1=np.arange(1000000)
array2= np.arange(1000000)
```

e quando fiz a seguinte operação:

```
array1*array2
```

obtive essa resposta:

```
array([         0,          1,          4, ..., -731379964, -729379967,
   -727379968])
```

E quando utilizei a função np.multiply() obtive a mesma resposta:

```
np.multiply(array1,array2)
```

Estou utilizando o jupyter notebook, não sei se isso interfere.

Comment: Arrumei a questão obrigado por me avisar.

Comment: Aqui (https://repl.it/@acwoss/sopt-question-387036) não deu esse problema. É somente isso o código mesmo?

Comment: Caro Thiago, isto ocorre porque provavelmente seu Python é 32bit, logo a arquitetura não suporta numeros grandes, no exemplo do  @AndersonCarlosWoss funciona porque o Repl.it provavelmente roda a versão 64bit.... Aqui uso 32bit, vejam o resultado, é o mesmo do Thiago: https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkoRi.png

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta.

Answer (score 0):

Isto provavelmente ocorre porque seu Python é **32bit**, logo a arquitetura não suporta números grandes, no exemplo do @AndersonCarlosWoss (https://repl.it/@acwoss/sopt-question-387036) funciona porque o [Repl.it](https://repl.it) provavelmente roda a versão 64bit do Python

Em meu ambiente (Windows) utilizo **32bit** também, veja que o resultado é o mesmo do ocorrido contigo:

> [image: exemplo de limitação do 32bit no Windows]

Resultado:

> ```
> [         0          1          4 ... -733379959 -731379964 -729379967]
> ```

Um exemplo da documentação para determinar se o seu Python é 32bit ou 64bit seria executando isto https://docs.python.org/3/library/platform.html#cross-platform, exemplo:

```
import sys

print(sys.maxsize > 2**32)
```

Se exibir `False` é porque é 32bit e não 64bit, então tirando a **"prova real"**, um teste no repl.it com Python3.6: https://repl.it/repls/DarkturquoiseDescriptiveRuntimelibrary

Retornou `True`, logo o código funciona como o esperado por ser 64bit, segue o resultado:

> [image: exemplo no repl.it em 64bit]

Resultado:

> ```
> [           0            1            4 ... 999994000009 999996000004
> 999998000001]
> ```